# Binary Search Tree Member Function

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble writing code to determine if certain data is present in my tree, this is the BinaryTreeNode class

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
  public:
    Data * nodeData;
    BinaryTreeNode * left;
    BinaryTreeNode * right;
```

the function I need to complete is (can't change this definition)

```
bool BinaryTreeNode::member(Data * data) const {
```

I've tried to create a variable like *currentnode = this* and use a while loop to check which side of the tree to progress down, then update currentnode, but I can't seem to get that to work. So I'm thinking maybe it is supposed to be accomplished with recursion? I've tried that but the program locks up.

If anyone could point me into the right direction it would be extremely helpful.

Here's one of my many attempts (this one trying recursion):

```
bool BinaryTreeNode::member(Data * data) const {
    if(nodeData == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (nodeData->compareTo(data) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    while(this != NULL) {
        if(nodeData->compareTo(data) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(nodeData->compareTo(data) == 1) {
            return left->member(data);
        }
        else if(nodeData->compareTo(data) == -1) {
            return right->member(data);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you have tried so that we can help you debug

Comment: Both of your attempts could do the job.  But we can't tell you where the bug is, obviously.

Comment: edited the op with my recursion attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(this != NULL)
```

In the first call to that function, `this` will never change to `NULL`.

**You can outright remove that one line.**  Then, just check for `NULL` in your two branches.

```
    if(left && nodeData->compareTo(data) == 1) {
        return left->member(data);
    }
    if(right && nodeData->compareTo(data) == -1) {
        return right->member(data);
    }
```

Once you've recursively checked the left and right trees, you're done.